# How to read SSL Certificate with Private and Public key inside docker container

Tags: docker-compose, ssl-certificate

I have a WebAPI application built using dotnet 6. This application encrypts some input xml files using SSL certificate private key. The SSL certificate rests on host machine which is mounted on docker image using docker-compose. Xmls to be encrypted also rests on the same folder where SSL certificate is present. When I try to read this certificate from the container, I get following error:

```
Type of Exception :Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException Exception Message: Object was not found. Exception Stack Trace:    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags).
```

However, if the same application is run on host machine directly without docker container it is able to read the certificate and encrypt the files. Any idea what could be the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding user:  "ContainerAdministrator" in docker-compose.yml solved the issue

```
services:
  myservice:
   user:  "ContainerAdministrator"
```